# How do I print a specific line from my array?

Tags: java, file-handling

I'm trying to build a payroll system for our project, complete with GUI and event handlers, but I got stuck at file handling.

I have a text file that looks somthing like this

```
1 Miguel 491
2 Jasper 323
3 Will 363
```

I want to retrieve a single line from that text 
Output

```
1 Miguel 491
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.FileNotFoundException; 
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.List;  
import java.util.Scanner; 
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.Label; import java.awt.event.*;

public class Main { public class panels extends JFrame{





         }
    public static void main(String[] args) {        

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Payroll by Miggy");
        frame.setSize(400,300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        Label idlabel;                     // Declare an Label instance called lblInput
        idlabel = new Label("Enter ID");
        JButton jbtok = new JButton("Ok");

        frame.add(jbtok);

        try {
            File f = new File("C:/Users/MIGXTREME/Desktop/Employee.txt");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);

            List<Employee> people = new ArrayList<Employee>();

            while(sc.hasNextLine()){
                String line = sc.nextLine();
                String[] details = line.split(" ");
                int Id = Integer.parseInt(details[0]);
                String name = details[1];
                int rate = Integer.parseInt(details[2]);
                Employee p = new Employee(Id, name, rate);
                people.add(p);
            }

           for(Employee p: people){
                System.out.println(p.toString());
           }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {         
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } }

class Employee{

    private int Id;
    private String name;
    private int rate;

    public Employee(int Id, String name, int rate){
        this.Id = Id;
        this.setName(name);
        this.rate = rate;
    }

  public int getId() {
    return Id; }


public void setGender(int Id) {
    this.Id = Id; }


public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name; }


public String getName() {
    return name; }


public int getrate() {
    return rate; }


public void setrate(int rate) {
    this.rate = rate; }

public String toString(){
    return this.Id + " " + this.name + " " + this.rate*4; } }
```

Comment: so what problem you are facing ?

Comment: Could you explain what is going wrong? What did you try that didnt work? Also, what is throwing an error? How is your text file written? 1 person per line? or more? You need to give us more details so we can try to help you, not do the work for you.

Comment: well there is no error actually, I just want to know how to print a specific line from the text file not all the lines..

Comment: without traversing in file its not possible to get data so in while put condition that matches your requirement & add only if it matches.

Comment: Wow! it worked thanks user3145373 ツ never figured the structure was wrong..

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the RandomAccessFile class. That will help traversing the file non-sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

just Do:

```
for(Employee p: people){
    if(p.name.equals("Miguel")){
        System.out.println(p.toString());
        break;
    }
}
```